# SIGABRT in Macos application

Tags: swift, macos, crash

I'm getting a SIGBART signal after the application is running a while.
I suspect that it is related to timer which is running in the background.

This is the code I'm using to invoke the recurrent timer:

```
 Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 20 , target: self, selector: #selector(self.scheduledEventHandler), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And this is the handler:

```
@objc func scheduledEventHandler()
{
     print("got event")
}
```

And lastly, this is the stacktrace:

```
    thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00007fff5182cfce libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x0000000100fbb1b4 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 333
    frame #2: 0x00007fff5178930a libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 127
    frame #3: 0x00007fff4f76bf8f libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 245
    frame #4: 0x00007fff4f76c12b libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 265
    frame #5: 0x00007fff50af0eab libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 105
    frame #6: 0x00007fff4f7877c9 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
    frame #7: 0x00007fff4f787478 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 99
    frame #8: 0x00007fff50aef139 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 40
    frame #9: 0x00007fff2a0f703e CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 638
    frame #10: 0x00007fff29416866 HIToolbox`RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286
    frame #11: 0x00007fff294165d6 HIToolbox`ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613
    frame #12: 0x00007fff29416354 HIToolbox`_BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
    frame #13: 0x00007fff27713a23 AppKit`_DPSNextEvent + 2085
    frame #14: 0x00007fff27ea8e6c AppKit`-[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
    frame #15: 0x00007fff27708831 AppKit`-[NSApplication run] + 764
    frame #16: 0x00007fff276d79d2 AppKit`NSApplicationMain + 804
    frame #17: 0x0000000100034d2d App`main at AppDelegate.swift:15
    frame #18: 0x00007fff516dd145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #19: 0x00007fff516dd145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

*Please note, that this task works well most of the time (crashes rarely).

I'll appreciate any suggestions to better understand the cause of such crash.

Comment: This is unlikely to be caused by a timer. Something's wrong in your code. Is the code in the handler the one that cause the problem or something more complex?

Comment: I'm not sure that the code inside the handler caused it, since the stack trace only shows core functions.

Comment: I understand your objection but I doubt it is a problem in the framework, looks like you have a memory management problem, but I can fail in this diagnosis.

Comment: Do you have perhaps a tip on how to debug/diagnose such event? is there an exception handler which might catch such an issue? I tried to catch signals but the stack trace is not visible, and it's too late.

Comment: You may have to use Instruments to observe runs... I think that is the best choice.